# How to query multiple SQL tasks in php for Wordpress?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I am looking for a way how to carry out multiple sql tasks using Wordpress php script.

So far, I have the following function, but it wont carry out all the tasks atm.

```
private function rename_products($product) {
    global $wpdb;

    // Replace product names and descriptions
    $sql = "UPDATE wp_posts SET post_title = REPLACE(post_title, 'Velikost Osuška', 'Osuška, Velikost');";
    $sql = "UPDATE wp_posts SET post_title = REPLACE(post_title, 'Velikost Ručník 50x100Velikost Ručník 50 x 100', 'Ručník, Velikost 50x100');";
    $sql = "UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'Velikost Ručník 50x100Velikost Ručník 50 x 100', 'Ručník, Velikost 50x100');";
    $sql = "UPDATE wp_posts SET post_excerpt = REPLACE(post_excerpt, 'Velikost Ručník 50x100Velikost Ručník 50 x 100', 'Ručník, Velikost 50x100');";

    $wpdb->query($sql);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You can concat all queries and can execute those in one go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can merge all the queries into one and get all the updated done. An update query supports multiple updates using `SET` statement separated by a comma.

```
UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_title = REPLACE(post_title, 'Velikost Osuška', 'Osuška, Velikost'),
post_title = REPLACE(post_title, 'Velikost Ručník 50x100Velikost Ručník 50 x 100', 'Ručník, Velikost 50x100'),
post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'Velikost Ručník 50x100Velikost Ručník 50 x 100', 'Ručník, Velikost 50x100'),
post_excerpt = REPLACE(post_excerpt, 'Velikost Ručník 50x100Velikost Ručník 50 x 100', 'Ručník, Velikost 50x100')
```